# How to bypass password authentication when booting into macOS Recovery

Tags: install, password, recovery, utilities

I have an Apple Silicon machine with FileVault enabled, and when I boot into macOS Recovery, it asks for a password before letting me use the utilities etc.

I have forgotten my password, so I cannot get past this initial password recovery app screen, but I need to use the integrated utilities.

I want to install macOS on a separate partition without erasing the existing installation and my data.

I have not found anything for a situation like this online.

*If somebody has an idea of how I can skip the password recovery utility and get to the macOS install tool, please help.*

**Additional info:**
I do know what the password could be, but I entered it incorrectly and now when I boot into the normal OS, it does not even try to check whether my password is incorrect or not. I do not know why this is since I did not use all 10 attempts before the password or the recovery key can only be entered in the Recovery OS for another 10 attempts each. (According to the apple support page regarding password logins)

I know that the Mac has stopped processing my password attempts in the normal OS because the password field immediately shakes after pressing enter without any delay at all and because I can try as many different combinations as I want without the message "Wait - minutes before next try".

I lost the recovery key. So I can't log in normally.

Comment: Did you store your recovery key in iCloud?

Comment: No, I do not have access to the recovery key

Comment: So you can't log into the machine normally?

Comment: Correct. I have added more information to the original question.